# Rock, Paper, Scissors - How to start a new game when there's a draw

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really new to coding in Python, and since I'm on basics, every code is literally a huge block full of messed up code. What I'm trying to do at the moment is a rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock game which will be transformed into a game later on with visual, hoping to be a basic app to my phone to sharp my learning, anyway, here's the code.

What I am trying to do is, when there's a draw with the player and the computer, ask the user if he wants to play again, I can't figure it out properly, I will appreciate any help.

```
import random

computerChoice = random.randint(1,5)
playerChoosing = True
answer = True

if computerChoice == 1:
    computerChoice = "rock"
elif computerChoice == 2:
    computerChoice = "paper"
elif computerChoice == 3:
    computerChoice = "scissors"
elif computerChoice == 4:
    computerChoice = "spock"
elif computerChoice == 5:
    computerChoice = "lizard"

while playerChoosing == True:
    print("rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock, What do you choose?")
    playerChoice = input()
    if playerChoice == "rock":
        print("you chose rock")
        playerChoosing = False
    elif playerChoice == "paper":
        print("you chose paper!")
        playerChoice = "paper"
        playerChoosing = False
    elif playerChoice == "scissors":
        print("you chose scissors!")
    playerChoice = "scissors"
    playerChoosing = False
elif playerChoice == "lizard":
    print("you chose lizard!")
    playerChoice = "lizard"
    playerChoosing = False
elif playerChoice == "spock":
    print("you chose spock!")
    playerChoice = "spock"
    playerChoosing = False
else:
    print("this is not an option, please try again")
    playerChoosing = True

input()

print("The computer chose: " +computerChoice+ "!")

input()
#lose


while answer == True:
    if playerChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "paper":
        print("you lose!, the rock was covered by the paper!")   
    elif playerChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "scissors":
        print("you lose!, scissors cut the paper in half")    
    elif playerChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "rock":
        print("you lose!, rock crushed the scissors")    
    elif playerChoice == "spock" and computerChoice == "lizard":
        print("you lose!, lizard poisons spock")    
    elif playerChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "spock":
        print("you lose!, spock smashes scissors")    
    elif playerChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "spock":
        print("you lose!, spock vaporizes the rock")   
    elif playerChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "lizard":
        print("you lose!, lizard eats paper")    
    elif playerChoice == "lizard" and computerChoice == "rock":
        print("you lose!, rock crushes lizard")    
    elif playerChoice == "lizard" and computerChoice == "scissors":
        print("you lose!, scissors kills lizard")    
    elif playerChoice == "spock" and computerChoice == "paper":
        print("you lose!, paper disproves spock")
#win   
elif playerChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "rock":
    print("you win!, the rock was covered by the paper!")    
elif playerChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "paper":
    print("you win!, scissors cut the paper in half!") 
elif playerChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "scissors":
    print("you win!, rock crushed the scissors!")    
elif playerChoice == "lizard" and computerChoice == "spock":
    print("you win!, lizard poisons spock!")   
elif playerChoice == "spock" and computerChoice == "scissors":
    print("you win!, spock smashes scissors!")   
elif playerChoice == "lizard" and computerChoice == "paper":
    print("you win!, lizard eats paper!")   
elif playerChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "lizard":
    print("you win!, rock crushes lizard!") 
elif playerChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "lizard":
    print("you win!, scissors kills lizard!")  
elif playerChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "spock":
    print("you win!, paper disproves spock!")
elif playerChoice == "spock" and computerChoice == "rock":
    print("you win!, spock vaporizes rock!")
#draw
elif playerChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "paper":
    print("It's a draw, want to try again?, please type YES or NO: ")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "yes":
        answer = False
    else:
        break
elif playerChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "rock":
    print("It's a draw, want to try again?, please type YES or NO: ")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "yes":
        answer = False
    else:
        break
elif playerChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "scissors":
    print("It's a draw, want to try again?, please type YES or NO: ")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "yes":
        answer = False
    else:
        break
elif playerChoice == "lizard" and computerChoice == "lizard":
    print("It's a draw, want to try again?, please type YES or NO: ")
    answer = input()

elif playerChoice == "spock" and computerChoice == "spock":
    print("It's a draw, want to try again?, please type YES or NO: ")
    answer = input()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Lucas. Please be aware, the expectation is that you try to solve any given problem yourself, and then describe your particular problem in detail, and include an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please see [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to wrap your code in a function definition called `play()`, or something similar. Then near the end:

```
answer = True

def play():
    # your code

    if playerChoice == computerChoice: 
        print "It's a draw, want to try again?, please type YES or NO: "
        # use a dictionary to convert; default answer is False
        answer = {'YES' : True, 'NO' : False}.get(input(), False)

if answer:
    play()
```

This is all strongly rooted in the idea of [Control Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow). Many languages, including Python, provide functions, classes, modules, if-else, and other control structures that allow you to control which direction your code *moves*. Many of these structures also help you to organize your code.

If the output of your code only needed to be *win*, *lose*, or *draw*, then you could use more advanced structures to get rid of your if-else statement. In my opinion, it's close to the best implementation in your case, but it's quite ugly when it's not wrapped in a function.

---

Here's a different way to approach the problem using python's built-ins:

```
import random

newgame = True
choosing = False

playerchoice = ''
computerchoice = ''

options = ['rock', 'scissors', 'paper', 'lizard', 'spock']

def play():
    global choosing, computerchoice, computerchoice, newgame
    choosing = True

    while choosing == True: # or while choosing 
        choose()

    result = get_result(playerchoice, computerchoice)

    if result[0] == 'Draw':
        print "It's a draw, want to try again?", "Please type YES or NO:"

        # convert input into uppercase string, use dictionary to convert to boolean
        # default to False
        newgame = {'YES' : True, 'NO' : False}.get(str(input()).upper(), False)
        return # leave function back into 'while newgame' loop
    else:
        # fun code that converts the first value into the win/lose string, and combines it with the outcome of the round
        # join uses the string ', ' in between the two things we print
        values = [{True : 'You win!', False : 'You lose!'}[result[0]], result[1]]
        string = ', '.join(values)
        print string

def choose():
    global playerchoice, choosing, computerchoice

    print "rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock. What do you choose?"
    playerchoice = input()

    if playerchoice in options: # if playerchoice == any option
        print 'you chose', playerchoice

        computerchoice = options[random.randint(0,4)] # take advantage of list indexes
        print 'computer chose', computerchoice

        choosing = False
    else: 
        print "this is not an option, please try again"

def get_result(playerchoice, computerchoice):
    results = {
               'rock' : {
                         'rock' : ('Draw',),
                         'paper' : (False, 'paper covers rock!'),
                         'scissors' : (True, 'rock crushes scissors!'),
                         'lizard' : (True, 'rock crushes lizard!'),
                         'spock' : (False, 'spock vaporizes rock!')
                        },
               'paper' : {
                          'rock' : (True, 'paper covers rock!'),
                          'paper' : ('Draw',),
                          'scissors' : (False, 'scissors cut paper!'),
                          'lizard' : (False, 'lizard eats paper!'),
                          'spock' : (True, 'paper disproves spock!')
                         },
               'scissors' : {
                             'rock' : (False, 'rock crushes scissors!'),
                             'paper' : (True, 'scissors cut paper!'),
                             'scissors' : ('Draw',),
                             'lizard' : (True, 'scissors kills lizard!'),
                             'spock' : (False, 'spock smashes scissors!')
                            },
               'lizard' : {
                           'rock' : (False, 'rock crushes lizard!'),
                           'paper' : (True, 'lizard eats paper!'),
                           'scissors' : (False, 'scissors kills lizard!'),
                           'lizard' : ('Draw',),
                           'spock' : (True, 'lizard poisons spock!')
                          },
               'spock' : {
                          'rock' : (True, 'spock vaporizes rock!'),
                          'paper' : (False, 'paper disproves spock!'),
                          'scissors' : (True, 'spock smashes scissors!'),
                          'lizard' : (False, 'lizard poisons spock!'),
                          'spock' : ('Draw',)
                         },
               }
    return results[playerchoice][computerchoice]

while newgame == True:
    play()
```

---

Python has some very powerful built-in types and functions, so I intentionally used them in the code above to the point of absurdity. Hopefully you'll look at the code and find new things to learn about Python.

When used well, if/else is sufficient, but I hope I've demonstrated a few powerful ways Python can simplify complex code. Little things like using dictionaries to convert are really useful to keep code concise. They come with a slight performance overhead, but execution speed isn't usually a priority if you use Python.

Edit: Avoid using global variables because they get really hard to debug if you forget the `global` keyword ^^; Another common debugging difficulty is when you have a tuple with one element `('Draw')` and forget to tell python it's a tuple by adding a comma...

Comment: Your version of the code is indeed better, and tidier, I did learn a few things from your code, hopefully in a near future I will be writing like that,  what I don't get is how is that your print doesn't need any parentheses?

Comment: @LucasMatheus It's what is called 'syntactic sugar'; many programming languages have shortcuts for really common code. In python, `print` is a function that doesn't need parenthesis. Python also uses tabs so that you don't need to type braces `{ ... }` around code.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is to make your code shorter
Maybe instead of trying to use so many if else, consider the following first:

```
r   0
s   1
p   2

you     player 2
Win
r   -   s           =   -1
s   -   p           =   -1
p   -   r           =    2

Lose
s   -   r           =    1
p   -   s           =    1
r   -   p           =   -2 

Draw
s   -   s           =    0
p   -   p           =    0
r   -   r           =    0
```

There are a set of values that you get when you subtract your choice with theirs. So winning will only result in -1 and 2.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that it simplifies in a lossy way; vaporization, crushing, and poisoning no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm semi-new to Python compared to some other people, but I've learnt a good amount so far. So here are some tips to solve your problem and other tips to make your code better. Now, I'm not totally sure what your exact problem is, but I believe you want to know how to start the game over if it's a tie.

Put the game into a `while` loop that's equal to True. Then if it's a tie, use the `continue` statement (if you're unsure what that is look it up) to restart the while loop. At end of the while loop put `break`.

I'm new to Stack Overflow, otherwise I'd post the code with the revisions to make it easier to understand. Also you don't need so many `elif` statements to check to see if its a tie. One simple `elif playerChoice == computerChoice:` should do it.

If you haven't learnt how to make functions yet, you should try simplifying your code with making your own. If you haven't learnt that yet, it's not too hard to learn and it might also help with restarting the game if there's a tie.

Another tip that I'm still working on myself is to add plenty of comments to code. I can't count how many programs I've returned to after a month or so, and I look at it confused, and ask what was the purpose of some function or statement. Hopefully I was helpful (my first posting on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Although is a simple advice, it was really helpful, thank you

Comment: _I'm new to Stack Overflow, otherwise I'd post the code with the revisions to make it easier to understand._ There is no restriction on new users posting code.